# how can I print this in MVC 4.0 View Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class student:

```
       public class Student
       {
          public int StudentId{get;set;}
          public string StudentName{get;set;}
          public int Age{get;set;}
          public List<Course> Courses{get;set;}
          public List<string> MobileNumbers{get;set;}
       }
```

And the Course class is:

```
       public class Course
       {
         public int CourseId {get;set;}
         public string CourseName {get;set;}
         public List<Staff> Staff {get;set;}
       }
```

The Staff class has the following structure:

```
      public class Staff
      {
        public int StaffId {get;set;}
        public string StaffName {get;set;}
      }
```

I have put the data in the ViewBag , but I am not able figuring it out how should I use foreach statement to print all those records in the following View.
View:

```
      <table class="tableStyle" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                <th>Courses</th>
                                <th>Staffs</th>
                                <th>Mobile Numbers</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        @foreach (Student stud in ViewBag.students)
                        {       
                            <tr>
                                <td>@stud.StudentName</td>
                              foreach(Course course in ViewBag.courses)
                              {  
                                <td>@course.CourseName</td>

                              }
                              foreach(Staff staff in ViewBag.staff)
                              {
                                    <td>@staff.StaffName</td>
                              }

                            </tr>
                       }
                    </table>
```

But, this prints courses taken by all the students for the single student as they are in the first foreach loop. Please , suggest me a way to do this...!!

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @DaleMarshall: yeah, I am using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your other viewbags.  You have references to your courses and staff in the student object.

```
<table class="tableStyle" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                <th>Courses - Staffs</th>
                                <th>Mobile Numbers</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        @foreach (Student stud in Viewbag.students)
                        {       
                            <tr>
                                <td>@stud.StudentName</td>
                                <td>
                              foreach(Course course in stud.courses)
                              {  
                                foreach(Staff staff in course.staff)
                                {
                                  @course.CourseName - @staff.StaffName </br>
                                }
                              }
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                       }
                    </table>
```

You may also want to consider making IEnumerable the model for your page by adding:

```
@model IEnumerable<myproject.Models.Student>
```

to the top of the page.  Then you will not need to use a Viewbag.